# C++ - Using a .cpp file in another?

Tags: c++, methods

just a simple question: Is it possible to use a .cpp file in another .cpp file - Like calling for it.

E.g.
File1.cpp:

```
#include < iostream > 
#include < string >
  using namespace std;

void method(string s);

int main()
{
  method("Hello World");
  return 0;
}

void method(string s)
{
  //get this contents from file2.cpp
}
```

and File2.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void method(string s)
{
   cout << s << endl;
}
```

So to be able to do something along the lines of that. 
So I dont stuff all my code into 1 cpp file

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have to link them. Normally, you'd include a header that declares `method` instead of doing it yourself.

Comment: @chris: not sure I follow u.

Comment: This is about the real basics: .h and .cpp files and linking. I think you should pick up a book or read a beginners tutorial. To answer the question, you can #include 'file2.cpp', but this is not standard practice.

Comment: TYpically, you'd want either to not implement `method(string s)` in file1.cpp for this to work. Or have a different name for `method` - as the compiler can't tell the two functions apart as it stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make a header file; eg File2.h, in which you put the prototype for each of the functions you want to reuse:

```
#ifndef FILE2_H_
#define FILE2_H_    

void method(string s);

#endif  /* FILE2_H_ */
```

then you need to include this header both in File2.cpp and File1.cpp:

```
#include "File2.h"
```

now in File1.cpp you can just call this function without declaring it:

```
int main()
{
  method("Hello World");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:
File2.h:

```
#ifndef __File2_H__
#define __File2_H__

// Define File2's functions...
void method(string s);

#endif
```

File2.cpp:

```
#include "File2.h"
// implement them....
void method(string s)
{
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

File1.cpp

```
// This include line makes File1.cpp aware of File2's functions
#include "File2.h" 
// and now you can use File2's methods inside method() below.
void method()
{
    method(string("I am batman"));
}
```

Then link them as @chris said (the following is shell script/commands):

```
# Compile them first
cc -o file1.o File1.cpp
cc -o file2.o File2.cpp
# Then link them
cc -o program file1.o file2.o
```

Comment: No discussion of header file?

Comment: indeed, this might work, but it is quite dirty in my opinion... header files are the way to go...

Comment: Granted, header files are smarter. I'll edit the answer.